# Python IDE under Xubuntu 32 bits

Tags: xubuntu, python, 32-bit, ide

I have installed Xubuntu on a computer with 1GB RAM and 32-bit processor (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS).

I am looking for a good Python IDE that I could use with this system. I tried to install PyCharm or Spyder, but they seem to be available only for 64 bits and they require more RAM. I have installed Vim but, if possible, it would be good to have a graphical editor. What are good options of Python IDEs for this machine?

Answer (score 3):

You may also try Visual Studio Code.

I've never tried Atom, but it was [claimed that VS Code is more powerful](https://medium.com/the-artificial-impostor/use-visual-studio-code-to-develop-python-programs-717d849c7106):

> I tried using Atom and PyCharm to write Python code before. Python
>   support in Atom wasn’t powerful nor easy to use enough for me. And
>   PyCharm is too heavy-weight and a simple format-on-save requires some
>   dancing around to be done. I think Visual Studio Code has found a good
>   middle ground: it’s lightweight enough and yet still powerful enough.

A 32bit version may be downloaded from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux32_deb).

If needed, you may check the following pages as some starting points:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

And if you wish, some extensions may be useful:

- https://medium.com/issuehunt/10-visual-studio-code-extensions-for-python-development-de0be51bbeed
- https://towardsdatascience.com/top-3-vs-code-extensions-for-python-and-data-science-7462dd4ee530

Comment: vscode uses almost as much memory as pycharm.  I use both for development, vscode is decent but I run into many issues with it not telling me there are issues in the code.

Answer (score 2):

I personnaly use Atom with Python. It's a great fully editable text editor with syntax higlighting and other packages that you can download.
It's very lightweight, and you can find it there : https://atom.io/